# Storing an escape sequence in a variable for use later

Tags: php, csv

This might seem somewhat trivial, but it's a curiosity that's been bugging me somewhat.

I have a front-end page where the user uploads a CSV file. They can select the delimiter, file, and so on, and then have the server process the request. If the user selects the "tab" option, for example, then '\t' is stored as the delimiter in a variable, which I can then retrieve from my model later.

The problem arises when I try to use that value, as-is;

```
$csv->setDelimiter($this->csv_delimiter);
```

Because it's not being properly treated as an escape sequence, League\Csv (the library I am using) will throw an exception, stating the delimiter must be a single character.

I can overcome this by doing so;

```
if($this->csv_delimiter == '\t'){
    $csv->setDelimiter("\t");
}
else{
    $csv->setDelimiter($this->csv_delimiter);
}
```

However to me this seems cumbersome and a bit of a code smell. I tried enclosing the variable in double-quotes within the `setDelimiter` method, but that doesn't work either. Is there a way to force a variable to work with escape sequences? Or perhaps I should be working with more literal representations, such as character codes/hex codes?

Edit:

I think I see the problem, now;

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'csv_delimiter')->dropDownList([',' => 'Comma',
                                                         ';' => "Semicolon",
                                                         '\t' => 'Tab']); ?>
```

I'm storing the literal string, rather than the escape sequence. The reason for this is that it's a required field. When I used double-quotations, it wouldn't work. I realise now that it's because jQuery is treating the tab as a blank value, and not accepting it, which is why I switched back to single-quotes.

I'll either have to remove the validation or apply a callback on the validator (likely), but both should resolve the issue.

Comment: where $this->csv_delimiter gets its value? can you show the code?

Comment: It's not really an issue of where it gets the value from. It's just stored as a value in a dropdown list. The value is '\t", it's just not being treated as an escape sequence.

Comment: there is a difference between '\t' and "\t" so it is important how you set the csv_delimiter parameter

Comment: @Pooya Yes, I see your point now. I think it's not being stored properly as the escape sequence in my dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enclose the variable like this: `$csv->setDelimiter("{$this->csv_delimiter}");` ?

I used this sample of code to check it:

```
$obj = json_decode(json_encode(array("a" => "\t")));

var_dump("{$obj->a}"); // output: string(1) "   "
```